# LinkedList<Node>' does not contain a definition for 'begin'

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

> `LinkedList<Node>` does not contain a definition for 'begin' and no extension method 'begin' accepting a first argument of type '`LinkedList<Node>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I rewrote this from c++ to C#, what function do I use instead of "begin" since there's no function for it in LinkedList?

Code

```
static int main 
{
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>> l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>>();
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>>.Enumerator itr;
    LinkedList<Node>.Enumerator itr1;
    Binary_Tree bt = new Binary_Tree();
    bt.insert(3);
    bt.insert(2);
    bt.insert(4);
    bt.insert(1);
    bt.insert(5);
    l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>>(bt.level());

    itr = l.GetEnumerator();
    while (itr.MoveNext())
    {

        itr1 = (itr.Current).begin();
        while (itr1.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.Write((itr1.Current).data);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ehh, `GetEnumerator` just like you did in `l`?

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure that the actual construct that you're looking for in c# goes something like `foreach(var current in l){/*do something*/}`. The compiler can write all the enumerator jazz for you. You can even nest them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: OP was asking what he/she should use instead of begin--I don't think OP misunderstood or doubted the error message.  I took the question to be more along the lines of "I knew how to do this in C++ and am finding I don't know how to do this in C#".

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of ways that you can approach this with or without iterators, and the comments so far are also useful and on target.

If you are interested in something that traverses the nodes explicitly (rather than, say, `foreach`, which certainly is a nice and simple approach), but does not need an iterator, you can use the `First` property of the LinkedList.  This uses 'LinkedListNode' (which is returned by `First`, a Node wrapper on the Node data item that supplies a `Next` and a `Previous`, etc.

```
var outerNode = l.First;
while (outerNode != null) {
    var innerNode = outerNode.Value.First;
    while (innerNode != null) {
        Console.Write(innerNode.Value.data);
        Console.Write(" ");
        innerNode = innerNode.Next;
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
    outerNode = outerNode.Next;
}
```